# Regex - Match URL Paths that contain a trailing /

Tags: regex

I am trying to match on any incoming requests that don't have a trailing slash. I also want to capture the URL path, to use in a capture group.  Here is what I've gotten so far.

**Incoming URL:**   `http://www.example.com/path/to/`

**Regex:**  `http:\/\/www.example.com\/(.*)[.\/]`

[Here's a link to the regex tester results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiGlV.jpg)

This captures what I want, but it always matches on all URLs - not the URLs that don't contain a trailing slash.

The regex processor is PERL based.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Perhaps, [`http:\/\/www.example.com\/(.*)$(?<!\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/qfE2l1/1) will work.

Answer (score 1):

To match URLs that do not end with `/`, use a *negative lookbehind* with an `$` anchor like below:

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/(.*)$(?<!\/)
                              ^^^^^^^^
```

`$` will assert the position at the end of the string, and the lookbehind will fail the match if there is a slash. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfE2l1/1).

Another way is with a `(?!.*\/$)` lookahead:

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/(?!.*\/$)(.*)
                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DHR9fr/1).

The `(?!.*\/$)` negative lookahead will fail the match after finding out that there is `/` at the end of the string (`$`). Note that `.*` (matches any 0+ chars) is necessary to get to the end of the string, you cannot just use `(?!\/$)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want a not-capture group at the end and match line start/end like this

`^http:\/\/www.example.com\/(.*)[^\/]$` (replace "match period or /" `[.\/]` with "not /" `[^\/]`, and surround with `^$`)

(You where so close!)

Add `s?` to make `https?` to allow an optional s if you don't care which protocol is being used.